# SPARQL: Variable must be included in group by clause

Tags: sparql, rdf

For every `sosa:FeatureOfInterest` (room), get the lowest temperature per day from the associated sensors for that room. There are 100 rooms. Each room has 3 sensors. The timeframe is one year.

Goal: Query to select lowest temperature per day per room from group of sensors **plus time of day when the temperature occurred**.

Example data (N3):

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> 
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
prefix ex: <http://www.example.com/> 

# Room FOIs
ex:room1Foi a sosa:FeatureOfInterest .
# ...
ex:room100Foi a sosa:FeatureOfInterest .

# Room 1 sensor observations 1/1/2021
ex:obs1Room1 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room1Foi ;
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "51.4"^^xsd:decimal .
ex:obs2Room1 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room1Foi .
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-01T08:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "50.2"^^xsd:decimal .
ex:obs3Room1 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room1Foi .
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-01T:16:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "49.8"^^xsd:decimal .

# Room 1 sensor observations 1/2/2021
ex:obs4Room1 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room1Foi ;
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-02T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "61.4"^^xsd:decimal .
ex:obs5Room1 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room1Foi .
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-02T08:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "60.2"^^xsd:decimal .
ex:obs6Room1 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room1Foi .
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-02T:16:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "59.8"^^xsd:decimal .

# ...

# Room 100 sensor observations 1/1/2021
ex:obs1Room100 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room100Foi ;
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "50.7"^^xsd:decimal .
ex:obs2Room100 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room100Foi .
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-01T08:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "51.6"^^xsd:decimal .
ex:obs3Room100 a sosa:Observation .
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ex:room100Foi .
    sosa:resultTime "2021-01-01T:16:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    sosa:observedProperty "TEMP"^^xsd:string ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult "48.0"^^xsd:decimal .

# Room 1 sensor observations 1/2/2021

# ...
```

One attempt:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix sosa: <http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/> 
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
prefix ex: <http://www.example1.com/> 
select ?oFoi ?day min(?val) as ?minTemp ?time where {
 {select ?f where {
  ?f a sosa:FeatureOfInterest .
 }}
 ?o a sosa:Observation ;
  sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?oFoi ;
  sosa:resultTime ?time ;
  sosa:observedProperty ?p ;
  sosa:hasSimpleResult ?val .
 filter(?oFoi = ?f) .
 bind(day(?t) as ?day) .
} group by ?oFoi ?day ?time
order by desc(?oFoi) asc(?day)
```

Result:

| oFoi | day | minTemp | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http://www.example.com/room1Foi | 1 | 51.4 | `2021-01-01 0:00:00` |
| http://www.example.com/room1Foi | 1 | 50.2 | `2021-01-01 8:00:00` |
| http://www.example.com/room1Foi | 1 | 49.8 | `2021-01-01 16:00:00` |
| http://www.example.com/room1Foi | 2 | 59.8 | `2021-01-02 16:00:00` |
| http://www.example.com/room1Foi | 2 | 60.2 | `2021-01-02 8:00:00` |
| http://www.example.com/room1Foi | 2 | 61.4 | `2021-01-02 0:00:00` |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

This doesn't work because `?time` must be included in the group by clause. Removing `?time` from group by clause will return the correct rows. However, `?time` is necessary to be included.

Ideal result:

| oFoi | day | minTemp | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http://www.example.com/room1Foi | 1 | 49.8 | `2021-01-01 16:00:00` |
| http://www.example.com/room1Foi | 2 | 59.8 | `2021-01-02 16:00:00` |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Update:**
This gets closer but still is including multiple results when two times in the same day have the same temperature (both results included):

```
select ?o2 ?oFoi2 ?day2 ?val2 sample(?t2) as ?tx2 ?p2 where {
  ?o2 a sosa:Observation ;
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?oFoi2 ;
    sosa:resultTime ?t2 ;
    sosa:observedProperty ?p2 ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult ?val2 .
  bind(day(?t2) as ?day2) .  
  filter(?oFoi2 = ?oFoi) .
  filter(?day2 = ?day) . 
  filter(?val2 = ?vx) . 

  {select ?oFoi ?day min(?val) as ?vx where {
      {select ?f where {
        ?f a sosa:FeatureOfInterest .
      }}
      ?o a sosa:Observation ;
        sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?oFoi ;
        sosa:resultTime ?t ;
        sosa:observedProperty ?p ;
        sosa:hasSimpleResult ?val .
      filter(?oFoi = ?f) .
      bind(day(?t) as ?day) .
    } group by ?oFoi ?day 
    order by desc(?oFoi) asc(?day)
  }

} group by ?o2 ?oFoi2 ?day2 ?p2 ?val2
```

Result:

| o2 | oFoi2 | day2 | val2 | tx2 | p2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http://www.example3.com/obs3Room100 | http://www.example3.com/room100Foi | 1 | 48 | `2021-01-01 16:00:00` | "TEMP"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| http://www.example3.com/obs6Room1 | http://www.example3.com/room1Foi | 2 | 59.8 | `2021-01-02 16:00:00` | "TEMP"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| http://www.example3.com/obs333Room1 | http://www.example3.com/room1Foi | 1 | **-9.8** | `2021-01-01 16:00:00` | "aTEMP"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| http://www.example3.com/obs33Room1 | http://www.example3.com/room1Foi | 1 | **-9.8** | `2021-01-01 7:59:00` | "aTEMP"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Oops: `?o2` is unnecessary and removing it from the above query results in the correct solution.

Comment: if you know there is only a single value of `?time` you can use the aggregate function `sample`: `select ?oFoi ?day (min(?val) as ?minTemp) (sample(?time) as ?timeVal)` and omit `?time` from the grouping part

Comment: @UninformedUser Just updated the question. Time and temperature are both needed. In this scenario that are only three times per sensor but there could be 20 or 30.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an outer `select` appears to solve this. Using an aggregate for the time such as `min()`, `max()`, `avg()`, `sample()`, etc. are all valid approaches for aggregating the time variable. (Adding an extra property `aTEMP` to help in understanding.)

Query:

```
select ?oFoi2 ?day2 ?val2 sample(?t2) as ?tx2 ?p2 where {
  ?o2 a sosa:Observation ;
    sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?oFoi2 ;
    sosa:resultTime ?t2 ;
    sosa:observedProperty ?p2 ;
    sosa:hasSimpleResult ?val2 .
  bind(day(?t2) as ?day2) .  
  filter(?oFoi2 = ?oFoi) .
  filter(?day2 = ?day) . 
  filter(?val2 = ?vx) . 

  {select ?oFoi ?day min(?val) as ?vx where {
      {select ?f where {
        ?f a sosa:FeatureOfInterest .
      }}
      ?o a sosa:Observation ;
        sosa:hasFeatureOfInterest ?oFoi ;
        sosa:resultTime ?t ;
        sosa:observedProperty ?p ;
        sosa:hasSimpleResult ?val .
      filter(?oFoi = ?f) .
      bind(day(?t) as ?day) .
    } group by ?oFoi ?day 
    order by desc(?oFoi) asc(?day)
  }

} group by ?oFoi2 ?day2 ?p2 ?val2
```

Result:

| oFoi2 | day2 | val2 | tx2 | p2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http://www.example3.com/room100Foi | 1 | 48 | `2021-01-01 16:00:00` | "TEMP"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| http://www.example3.com/room1Foi | 2 | 59.8 | `2021-01-02 16:00:00` | "TEMP"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| http://www.example3.com/room1Foi | 1 | -9.8 | `2021-01-01 7:59:00` | "aTEMP"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |